# How to install ROracle on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: r

This is a follow on to [How to install ROracle package on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046324/how-to-install-roracle-package-on-windows-7)

I'm getting the following error trying to build ROracle

> ** testing if installed package can be loaded
>   
> Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :
>   unable to load shared object 'D:/Users/a101/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/ROracle/libs/x64/ROracle.dll':
>   LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I have RTools and 64-bit Oracle Instantclient installed

 I execute the following from an Admin privieledged command line:

> set OCI_LIB64=C:/Oracle/instantclient_12_1_x64
>   
> set OCI_INC=C:/Oracle/instantclient_12_1_x64/sdk/include
>   
> "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL --build ROracle_1.1-10.tar.gz

I've searched around and what I've found says this error is caused by building in mixed mode. I.e. 32-bit R with 64-bit Oracle client library or vice versa. I've been looking at this for many (many) hours and I believe I'm using all 64-bit (OS, R, Oracle client library). All the trace messages seem to indicate 64-bit everywhere.

Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Comment: Nevermind. I believe that I've found the error. I did a dependecy walk on the ROracle.dll and it appears to find the 32-bit version of OCI.dll thereby preventing the successful loading of the ROracle DLL.

Comment: How do you do a dependency walk? I'm having the exact same issue!

Answer (score 1):

To run dependency walk use Dependecy Walker, choose opening ROracle.dll in this app. I had the same issue since ROracle.dll was searching for OCI x64 (Oracle client), whereas I had x86 version of it installed on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same question, with 64bit windows and R...
Since I shifted the `ROracle` from 32bit to 64bit some days before. After changing the OCI_LIB64, OCI_INC and also add the 64bit instantclient dir to the env variable `Path`, it works fine in R and RStudio.

But I set up a task scheduler before, using Rscript.exe to run a RCode every day. That task failed since the shift with the same error:"Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : unable to load shared object 'E:/app/R_lib/3.4/ROracle/libs/x64/ROracle.dll': LoadLibrary failure: %1 is not a valid Win32 application."

My final solution is to restart the computer...And the task scheduler works again....guess there should be some 32bit file stored temporarily and need to be deleted before using 64bit ROracle...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Oracle Client 32 and 64 bits witk SDK folder directory to the Windows System enviromental variables path. Also need to install rjava package (install java 64 bits) and set JAVA_HOME in R sys.setenv().

```
install.packages("rJava")       #Install Java 64 bits
library(rJava)                  #Not Errors

Sys.setenv("OCI_LIB64"="C:/instantclient_12_2_64bits")
Sys.setenv("OCI_LIB32" = "C:/instantclient_12_2_64bits")
Sys.setenv("ORACLE_HOME" = "C:/instantclient_12_2_64bits")

Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_241')

install.packages(paste0(path,"/ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz"), repos = NULL, type = "source")
library(ROracle)
```

The last message in the install process should be DONE!

In the Windows System enviromental path:

```
C:\instantclient_12_2_64bits;
C:\instantclient_12_2_64bits\sdk;
C:\instantclient_12_2_32bits;
C:\instantclient_12_2_32bits\sdk;
```

hope this works!