# How to install ROracle package?

Tags: roracle

I am trying to install ROracle package using `install.packages("ROracle")`  but every time i am getting this message `"Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘ROracle’"`

```
These will not be installed
```

I am not able to find the solution for this, How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows? For Linux I went through the process today and posted my recipe [here](https://thraxys.wordpress.com/2016/10/25/install-roracle-on-linux/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install ROracle package on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046324/how-to-install-roracle-package-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

from a past post.
[How to install ROracle package on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046324/how-to-install-roracle-package-on-windows-7)

Download binary from oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/r/roracle/downloads/index.html

The run the following command in r, substituting the file path:

```
setwd('xxxxx')   # set to path of download
install.packages('ROracle_1.2-1.zip', repos = NULL)
Then load the library and use the package - you may have to change XXXX to whatever is in your TNS Names:

library('ROracle')
drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
con <- dbConnect(drv, "USER GOES HERE", "PASSWORD GOES HERE", dbname='XXX')
test connection:

dbReadTable(con, 'DUAL')
```

was able to install from source and download the pre compiled addin directly from oracle

Comment: this doesn't work for everyone `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ROracle’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):`

Answer (score 0):

Are you on `CentOS7`?

I've grappled the issue for a long while and have had to document my findings [here](https://www.cjvirtucio.co/posts/roracle-centos7/). But the bird's-eye view of the process is:

1. Install oracle instant-client with `yum`.
2. Set the `OCI_LIB` and `OCI_INC` environment variables.
3. Run `ldconfig`.
4. Call `install.packages('ROracle')`

It also helps to use a proper package management tool like [packrat](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/) so that you never have to go through this process ever again.

Comment: There are some issues blocking CRAN package uploads, so the most recent ROracle driver can be found at https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/r/roracle/downloads/index.html

Comment: That page requires you to sign-on, though. It's not a repo that you can just `curl` the file from, and therefore wouldn't be automation-friendly.

Comment: Indeed, not ideal; but CRAN folk have been remarkably hard to contact to get a resolution on the CRAN package issues.