# Unable to connect to Oracle with ROracle package

Tags: r, oracle, roracle

I am trying to use ROracle package to connect to the oracle db from Windows desktop, I am getting this error:

```
library(ROracle)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ROracle’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/e598140/Documents/R/R-3.4.1/library/ROracle/libs/x64/ROracle.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, you do not indicate what OS you are on.  Suppose you are on a Windows 7 system, this could help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046324/how-to-install-roracle-package-on-windows-7

Comment: Maybe a stupid question: did you use the package manager to get ROracle?

Comment: ROracle has pretty involved compilation instructions for both Windows and Linux. Assuming you read and followed those instructions, the least you could do would be to outline how those steps went for you and what specifically you did and whether there were any errors or hiccups during the compile.