# How to connect Rstudio with oracle database?

Tags: sql, r, oracle, rstudio

I tried to connect with Rstudio with Oracle Database 12c using RODBC driver.

```
conn <- odbcConnect('driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver;server=102.83.1.1;database=ABC;trusted_connection=true')
```

Warning messages:

```
1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver;server=102.83.1.1;database=ABC;trusted_connection=true") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver;server=102.83.1.1;database=ABC;trusted_connection=true") :
  ODBC connection failed
```

Connected and I am able to fetch the data from my database.

Comment: check out `ROracle` package

Comment: I tried to install this package but I got an error message.                                                                 install.packages('ROracle')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Clinevo4/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
The package which is only available in source form, and may need
  compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘ROracle’
  These will not be installed

Comment: you will need to compile the package using Rtools. More instructions can be found here http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/web/packages/ROracle/INSTALL and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046324/how-to-install-roracle-package-on-windows-7